# Check if date is within range in PHP strtotime

Tags: php, datetime

I have searched through SO but the answers that I've tried doesn't seem to solve my problem. 
I have this simple code snippet where the user will input a numeric date, and a month, and the app will return the corresponding Zodiac Sign.

```
$birthdate = $_POST["birthdate"];
$birthmonth = (ucwords(strtolower($_POST["month"])))

//validations here. . .

    $tmp = $birthmonth . " " . $birthdate;
    $tmp2 = date_create_from_format('M j', $tmp);

    $formatted_dob = date_format($tmp2, 'm-d-Y'); 
    $dob = strtotime($formatted_dob);

    echo $formatted_dob;

    if ($dob >= strtotime('01-20-2016') && $dob <= strtotime('02-18-2016')) {
        echo "Aquarius"; 
    } elseif ($dob >= strtotime('02-19-2016') && $dob <= strtotime('03-20-2016')){          
        echo "Pisces";
    }
```

Those `echo` stuff outside the `if-else` block are working fine, however if I input a value of 25 and February (which later on results to `02-25-2016`), it always output `Aquarius`. How do you compare two `strtotime`values?

I've tried using `DateTime` object but it only gives me an error, which is another story. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:
Change the order of your date (*your format on your date 01-20-2016 m-d-Y that's why when you convert it it becomes 1970-01-01 'Y-m-d' but if you change it into 2016-01-20 'Y-m-d' on your date range the code will work just fine in else-if.

```
$birthdate = $_POST["birthdate"];
$birthmonth = (ucwords(strtolower($_POST["month"])))

//validations here. . .

    $tmp = $birthmonth . " " . $birthdate;
    $tmp2 = date_create_from_format('M j', $tmp);

    $formatted_dob = date_format($tmp2, 'm-d-Y'); 
    $dob = strtotime($formatted_dob);

    echo $formatted_dob;
$dobcompare = date_create(date('m/d/Y', $dob));
$aqstartdate = date_create(date('m/d/Y', strtotime('2016-01-20')));
$aqenddate = date_create(date('m/d/Y', strtotime('2016-02-18')));
$pistartdate = date_create(date('m/d/Y', strtotime('2016-02-19')));
$pienddate = date_create(date('m/d/Y', strtotime('2016-03-20')));

    if ($dobcompare >= $aqstartdate && $dobcompare <= $aqenddate) {
        echo "Aquarius"; 
    }
    elseif ($dobcompare >= $pistartdate && $dobcompare <= $pienddate) {
        echo "Pisces"; 
    } else {          
        echo "IDK";
    }
```

Modify it in your need.

This is the example [enter link description here](http://codepad.org/6QxfaTUa)

Comment: The `date_create` was working fine, thanks. But it doesn't work with else-if. I have 12 conditions filtering that kind of validation. @LeeBalino

Comment: @Cyval updated my answer. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: I have tried also your code just change the date you are entering on strtotime change it from m-d-Y to Y-m-d because it is the one causing the error you had earlier. @Cyval

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. :)